# JS: Adding class to container, in an if-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a small script with an if-statement: I want the condition to be, that if the class `"page-title"` contains "Welcome" it will add the class `"excluded"` to the element with the other class called `"example"`. This is the js-code I've tried so far without luck:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if(".page-title:contains('Welcome')"){
                document.getElementsByClassName("example").addClass("excluded");
            }
            else{
                
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple fix with js

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<h1 class="page-title">Welcome</h1>
<div class="example"> Example sample div</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

    if($('.page-title').text() == 'Welcome') {
        $('.example').addClass('excluded'); 

    }else{
      // code here 
    }
            
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that by selecting container with your class with jQuery, using `text()` method on it and trying to find `"Welcome"` in it. Try below code:

```
if($('.page-title').text().includes('Welcome')) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.page-title').text().indexOf('Welcome')){
        $(".example").addClass("excluded");
    }
});
```

You will need to decide which container/element you wish to add the 'excluded' class to, if you're finding that by using a class, you would write: `$(".class-name-of-element-here").addClass("excluded");` or with an ID: `$("#id_of_element_here").addClass("excluded");`

Notice when searching for a container or element by ID, we use `#` and a class with `.`

Any example of this is: `$('.page-title')` you're looking for any element on the page with a class of `page-title`

When you're using `addClass`, you do not need to specify the `.` as a prefix, because we are specifically looking for a class.

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 problems:

1: `document.getElementsByClassName("example").addClass("excluded");` is a mix of javascript and jQuery.

- javascript way: `document.getElementsByClassName("example").classList.add("excluded");`
- jQuery way: `$(".example").addClass("excluded");`

2: `if(".page-title:contains('Welcome')"){` is a valid if statement. use `if ($(".page-title:contains('Welcome')")) {`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".page-title:contains('Welcome')")) {
    $(".example").addClass("excluded");
  } else {
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".page-title:contains('Welcome')")) {
    $(".example").addClass("excluded");
  } else {

  }
});
```

```css
.example.excluded {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-title">Welcome to the world</div>

<div class="example">Is this excluded</div>
```